# Find the sum of all values of $x$ which satisfy the following systems of equations:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Systems of equations are as follows:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
y&=x^2-5x+5\\
z&=x^2-12x+35\\
y^z&=1\\
x,&y,z \in\mathbb{R}\\
\end{aligned}\right.$$

I got the obvious $x=5,7,1$ and $4$ but apparently there are other answers as the sum should equal to $20$ and the answers I got sum to $17$; and if $z=0$, $y$ can be anything and if $y=1$, $z$ can be anything.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility: $y=-1$ and $z$ is an even integer yields the unique $(x,y,z) = (3,-1,8)$ and now your $x$ values do sum to $20$.

Comment: I think, it should be $y>0$ by the domain of $y^z.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If $y=-1$ and $z$ is any integer, then $y^z$ is well-defined.

Comment: See please better the given. $z\in\mathbb R$, For $y=-1$ take $z=\frac{1}{2}.$ The domain of $y^z$ it's $\{(y,z)|y>0,z\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Why do you insist that $y^z=1$ restricts the domain of $y$, but not the domain of $z$? It is well-defined for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$ if we restrict $z$ to positive integers, for example.

Comment: @Servaes We work with real numbers. If we'll work with natural numbers it would be another problem.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg the way the OP posed the problem, find the real numbers $x,y,z$ that satisfy the given system of equations. From that point of view, any values you pick, as long as they satisfy the equations for that value set, are considered solutions.

Comment: @gt6989b I can not agree. I am sorry. it's fundamentally.

Answer (score -1):

There are infinitely many values of $x$ satisfying this system. For if you write the second equation as $z=x^2-5x+5-7x+30,$ and substitute for $x^2-5x+5$ using the first equation, we get $$z=y-7x+30.$$ Finally, the last equation implies $z=0$ or $y=1.$

If $z=0,$ then $y=7x-30$ and if $y=1,$ then $z=31-7x.$ Thus we have the families of solutions $(\lambda,7\lambda-30,0)$ and $(\mu, 1, 31-7\mu).$ The last case is when $z=0$ and $y=1,$ which gives the singleton $(31/7, 1, 0).$ Thus, you literally can't add all the values of $x$ satisfying the relation as $\lambda$ and $\mu$ can be any real number.